# Why does an ad page open when I browse my websites's wp-admin page?

Tags: themes, wp-admin, errors, dashboard

While I try to edit my website via Wordpress and open any wordpress page after logging in, the page shows an ad page and I am not able to edit my website.
[image: The image below shows the ad page that I am getting.]
The ad keeps appearing when I try to edit any post or open the dashboard of wordpress but does not show on the actual website.
How do I remove it and be able to edit the website?
Thank you.

Comment: You've probably been hacked. Review this: https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/ And keep in mind that this is not the right place for this kind of question. This would be better directed to the WordPress support forums.

Comment: Should be noted that you have to keep Elementor and other plugins like that up to date...  Elementor has had about 40 security vulnerabilities exposed since 2019.  https://vuldb.com/?search  Search for Elementor and scroll to the bottom to see the list.  Even if you have updated, it's possible one of them was exploited before you had the chance.  I'm just using Elementor as an example, but look at all the third party plugins and themes you have installed, any one could be in that DB.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there are an infinite number of possibilities that could cause this.
First you have to change the name of the activated theme and plugins from the file manager.
Then log in, in case this redirect did not occur
You can start activating plugins and theme one by one until you find out what caused this